# Can dependency:build-classpath build from a template?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I use `dependency:build-classpath` to produce the `cp.txt` listing the dependency JARs which I don't want bundled together with mine.

The shell-script launching my program is a one-liner:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec java -cp `cat cp.txt`:MyOwn.jar MyOwn "$@"
```

Though this works, I'd like the shell script itself to be generated -- from a template -- with only the class-path substituted by Maven.

Can I provide such a template to the maven-dependency-plugin -- or a comparable one?

Alternatively, can I add the command generating it from a template-file found under `src/` somewhere as a separate "target" (forgive the `make` and `ant` term)?

Comment: Have you considered of adding the list of library jars to the Manifest?  [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html#:~:text=By%20using%20the%20Class%2DPath%20header%20in%20the%20manifest%2C%20you%20can%20avoid%20having%20to%20specify%20a%20long%20%2Dclasspath%20flag%20when%20invoking%20Java%20to%20run%20your%20application.) says  "By using the `Class-Path` header in the manifest, you can avoid having to specify a long `-classpath` flag when invoking Java to run your application."

Comment: I have, yes, but the runtime will differ depending on the machine -- and the application-instance on it. So it has to be changeable -- based on a runtime variable, for example...

Comment: I would suggest to create an executable jar file via maven-shade-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin... So it can be reduced to `java -jar ...` ..?

Comment: If you like to save RAM etc. you could go to native compile via Graal.. and make use of effective algorithms etc. and use only deps which are really needed that saves a lot (also in meaning of diskspace and RAM)..

Comment: @MikhailT. what do you mean by: `wide use by today's programmers, `?

Comment: That means violating the share nothing principle (if you rely on external deps which makes updating etc. more complicated etc.) and also inside containers today etc. or running apps not inside containers is even easier than the things you save in comparison to the save resources (not to mentiond about maintainance). The argument about RAM will not help in such situation because each started JVM has it's own RAM requirements. Using a classpath will not reduce the required size of RAM except you go back to times using app server to share things which procuces of lot of other issues.

Comment: Maybe this can help here: https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Comment: Anyone seriously advancing the "share nothing" *nonsense* must not have heard of _shared libraries_ (also known as DLLs in the Windows world), which took over the statically-linked executable decades ago -- except in some few specialized cases. There being different JVMs is irrelevant -- if A.jar and B.jar, each executed in its own JVM, both use a common X.jar, the OS kernel only needs to  open the X.jar _once_. But if they both contain a copy of X _inside_ them, there is no way for the OS to know it, and additional RAM must be used.

Comment: The [AppAssembler-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) does look promising, thank you. Unfortunately, although it does use templates, there is no way at the moment to provide a _custom_ one -- resulting in multi-screen scripts containing unneeded cruft (like Cygwin and Darwin special handling)... Oh, well. Thanks again.